# Semantic difference between seemingly equivalent sentence

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference between the following (math related) sentences?

1. Assuming A and B, we derive a bound on X, which is of order n.
2. Assuming A and B, we derive a bound on X of order n.

Comment: The "relativisers" ***which*** and ***that*** (with possible associated copula TO_BE = ***is*** here) are *optional* in contexts like this. Whether or not to include them is a stylistic choice which has no effect on meaning. Just as it makes no difference if you alter the sequence to *...we derive a bound **of order n on X***, for example. There are usually multiple semantically equivalent ways of expressing the same thing in English. Equally, the comma makes no difference - but it *should* only be there ***if you would produce a pause in speech at that point***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yes. One of the unforgiveable curses. Wiz-deletion.

Comment: I read (1) as meaning that the bound, after derivation, is seen to be of order n.  I see (2) as meaning we decided to derive a bound with a specified order. As in, “order n is sufficient for our purposes.”

Comment: In 2, "of order n" could be modifying/complementing the verb "derive" rather than the noun phrase "a bound on X". ("Of"-phrases seldom modify verbs but it's possible: "He told me of his travels.")

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That's the term I always tend to forget because imho the most common manifestation involves "deleting" ***that*** rather than an actual ***wh-*** word. But we have a tag for it, so I've edited that in to the question. Ty for the nudge.

Comment: (1) is ambiguous as to whether the unnamed bound on X is of order n, or whether X is of order n. In real math without letters instead of words, it might be clear in context that X can't be of order n, whereas its bound can be. But, as they say, garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's a good point. So, "a bound of order n on X" is a better option to resolve any ambiguity.

Comment: @StuartF That might be possible, except that "of order X" doesn't seem like a prepositional phrase that could modify "derived".

Comment: Similar to @Jim's comment, I interpret  "which is of order n" to mean that the order happens to be n, or it's just incidental that it's of order n. Omitting "which" suggests that it's a direct consequence. The difference is subtle and often not significant.